# the facebook apps secure canvas URL

Tags: facebook, security, user-interface, facebook-canvas

I have some question about the facebook apps  secure canvas URL.

1. For the facebook apps secure canvas URL or secure page tab URL, does it require a specific kind of SSL Certificates, or any kind of them is fine??
2. As I am using one domain to host all things in different apps, is it fine for different apps using the same security domain?
3. For example, if I bought a SSL for my domain, let's say it is http://abc.com. What I need to type in the secure canvas URL box is https://abc.com, right? Do I got it correct?

Answer (score 3):

**answer 1.**
any ssl certifcate is ok. you can buy i.e. namecheap.com rapidsslonline.com for cheap ssl for your live app.
for your develop app you can create `self signed certificate` for free

**answer 2.** as you host your apps in this form:

- https://myappportal.com/firstapp
- https://myappportal.com/secondapp

it is sufficient having your ssl for myappportal.com. however if they are:

- https://firstapp.myappportal.com
- https://secondapp.myappportal.com

issue becomes sub domains which means you need sertifcate for *.myappportal.com

**answer 3.** correct example.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't necessarily need a specific SSL but you need one that is trusted by browsers. For example I'm using a free one from my host (Siteground) and an error shows to say that it's insecure
2. I have all of my apps on one domain... I use Joomla so have myrurl.co.uk, myurl.co.uk/fbapp, myurl.co.uk/fbapp2. That way you only need to have the SSL installed for the one URL
3. For the secure canvas box it would have to be `https://abc.com`, you need to have the `/` at the end otherwise Facebook doesn't recognize it as a url. But make sure you put the url of where your Facebook app is... the Facebook App in effect is just an iFrame that shows your website or the app you have created with a Facebook frame. So put in what you'd put in your browser to get to your app