# Does Facebook trust StartSSL Class 1 (free) certificate for embedded video players?

Tags: facebook, ssl, embed, ssl-certificate

I am trying to get an embedded video player to work in facebook. When in accessing facebook insecurely (http) everything works fine, i.e. the player gets embedded. When switching to https in facebook, the player is not embedded, but the original video url is opened in a new window.

I understand that the swf player has to be served over https too and I installed a [free StartSSL Class 1 certificate](http://www.startssl.com/?app=1) on our server. Unfortunately facebook does not seem to like it.

I guess Facebook has to trust the certificate to embed the player and it seems like it does not. Does anybody have an embedded video player running on a server with a free StartSSL certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook does not case about your certificate.
It only asks enter : **https**://myapp.com in to secure canvas url.

You can even create also self trusted certificate for your app, I mean:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7818333/492258

Comment: Something similar just solved my problem. For an embedded player you have to add the `org:video:secure_url` property. 

`<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/movie.swf" />
 `

Thought I'd seen that somewhere before but then could not find it in the documentation.