# Facebook Tab App and SSL Certiifcate

Tags: facebook, ssl, https, facebook-apps

I am developing 2 tab app's for Facebook and I know I need an SSL certificate but I cannot find any information as to the grade/spec of the SSL certificate I need.

Because of the high costs of some ssl's I am limited on what I am authorised to use/get.
So to start I have to use [Heart Internet](http://www.heartinternet.co.uk/website-security/ssl-certificates) for the SSL so would the Simple SSL be ok for the apps?

Does anybody know where I can find such information?

Comment: possible duplicate of [the facebook apps secure canvas URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817011/the-facebook-apps-secure-canvas-url)

Comment: thanks I I never came across that earlier as my search terms were different so thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook checks if You have https url, it does not matter how safe your certificate is. I have used the cheapest available. Around 15$ few years back.

You can even generate certificate yourself, only it will throw "untrusted certificate" in user's browser and that is not pretty, but it works well for your private test version.